# PHP Mockery not calling mocked method from within mock

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

I've been trying to use Mockery to assert that a method is called from within another method, when an exception is thrown. So as an example:

```php
public function testOtherMethodIsCalled() {

    $client = m::mock('Client');
    $client
        ->shouldReceive('getFoo')
        ->andThrow(new FooNotAvailableException);

    $controller = m::mock('Controller[otherMethod]');
    $controller
        ->shouldReceive('otherMethod')
        ->once();

    $controller->setClient($client);
    $controller->firstMethod();
}
```

Obviously the names have been simplified, but that's line for line identical in every other way to what I have. In the code, when `FooNotAvailableException` is caught I return the call to `otherMethod()`.

The problem is that when run it, I get this error:

> Mockery\CountValidator\Exception: Method otherMethod() from Controller should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times.

That's because internally the original, unmocked `otherMethod()` is being called. If I were to call it from within the test, like this:

```
$controller->otherMethod();
```

The test passes.

Why is that, and how would I write the test for what I want to test?

Comment: Your example is missing the class definition of `Client` and `Controller`. Stackoverflow requires that you proved a self-containing example, if you do not provide these definitions all we can say is that that method is not called by the missing definition.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without the full code source, but i believe that this is what is occurring:

Your code:

```
$client = m::mock('Client');
$client
    ->shouldReceive('getFoo')
    ->andThrow(new FooNotAvailableException);
```

So far so good. No problem yet.

```
$controller = m::mock('Controller[otherMethod]');
$controller
    ->shouldReceive('otherMethod')
    ->once();

$controller->setClient($client);
$controller->firstMethod();
```

Now, we run into a problem. I'm assuming that the code under test is redirecting to another URL. When that occurs, you're going to instantiate another Controller. The Controller that you instantiated is not going to be the Controller that is instantiated by "m::mock('Controller[otherMethod]')". So, obviously the mocked instance won't ever receive the "otherMethod".

Depending on how your code under test is actually written, the proper way to test this may be to assert that a Redirect::to has been called from the function that handles the FooNotAvailableException.